# How can I check if the current date today is even or odd?

Tags: c#, date

I really dont know how and I couldnt find a question about it so here I am. I'm very much a beginner so excuse me if this is an obvious question

Comment: What do you mean by an 'even date' or an 'odd date'? Only looking at the day of the month?

Comment: What does it mean to be even or odd for a date ?

Comment: I reckon, if the `Day` of a full `Date` - is odd or even?

Comment: I had an odd day yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
var oddDate = (DateTime.Now.Day % 2) == 1;
```

Comment: Or `var oddDate = (DateTime.Now.Day + DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Year) % 2 == 1` if we are counting all date components